# Simple dup2 function not working on ubuntu

Tags: c, unix, dup2

Can someone please tell me why this basic implementation of dup2 is not working.
When i run it the output is not redirected but is simply printed on the standard output.

```
   #include<unistd.h>
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<sys/types.h>
   #include<fcntl.h>

   void main(int argc,char *argv[] )
   {
      int fd,nread;
      char buf[4096];
      if(fd=open(argv[1],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IROTH|S_IRGRP)<0)
          printf("error opening");

      printf("fd=%d",fd);
      if(dup2(fd,STDOUT_FILENO)==-1)
            printf("error in duplicating");

       while(nread=read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,4096))
           write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,nread);

     }
```

Comment: Please mind operator precedence: `<` trumps `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(fd=open(argv[1],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IROTH|S_IRGRP)<0)
```

Please mind operator precedence (`<` trumps `=`), use parentheses. You are setting `fd` to 0 (stdin) on success.

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,nread);
```

This line fails because stdin is not open for writing.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `fd` is set after relational operation so use parenthesis to avoid it as,

```
if((fd=open(argv[1],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IROTH|S_IRGRP))<0)
```

since you dint use these parenthesis to assign the value for `fd` first then perform the comparison, fd was getting set to `0`.